# How to convert factor column to original values

Tags: r

I have an integer column that has factor applied to it:

```
col <- factor(list("3", "4", "3", "3"), labels = c("a", "b"), levels = c(3, 4))
```

If I convert that column to integer, I get:

```
> as.integer(col)
[1] 1 2 1 1
```

While I want to get original list of 3 and 4.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: We had almost exactly the same question here [earlier today](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36836789/4770166)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original values, 3 and 4, are permanently lost in your current code. The easiest way to keep them around is to use them as your labels.

```
col <- factor(list("3", "4", "3", "3"), labels = c("3", "4"), levels = c(3, 4))
```

Another way would be to store the mapping prior to factor conversion.